# reorder the hostsfile on linux

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I am looking for a one liner script to reorder the host file on a server

```
192.168.1.10    server1.domain.com server1 server1.managment
```

The hostname on the server is “server1” ( always the short domain) 
I am looking for the output to be

```
192.168.1.10    server1  server1.domain.com server1.managment
```

I am hoping I can do this with sed or awk in bash but struggling with this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simple `awk` solution.

```
awk '{print $1"\t" $3 " " $2 " " $4}' /etc/hosts
```

We just swap the columns around, `awk` uses space as its standard delimiter, so we say print column 1 then a tab, then print column 3 followed by a space...then 2 etc...